# Is this the result of Sell Market?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading

I saw a deep red line this morning. That means there is a lower than usual transaction. What happened there? Does it indicate someone "Sell Market" and somebody else is waiting at the much lower location and just catch it?

[image]

Comment: It's probably bad data.

Answer (score 1):

It *can* be a large ‘sell at market’ order (by an unsophisticated or panicked seller) that went through the whole order book. But chances are it’s bad data or bad display.